# What is geometric verification?

Tags: number-theory

I just started to read "Friendly Introduction to Number Theory". Now I'm trying 
 exercises 1-2

> 1.2. Try adding up the first few odd numbers and see if the numbers you get satisfy some sort of pattern. Once you find the pattern,
>   express it as a formula. Give a geometric verification that your
>   formula is correct.

https://www.math.brown.edu/~jhs/frintch1ch6.pdf

I think the pattern is `Σ[n=0..n](2*n + 1)`

But what is geometric verification? How should I answer this question?

[image]

Comment: That's not the pattern they're looking for. Do you see the pattern in the numbers $1,4,9,16,25,36$...

Comment: @MattSamuel Hello! I can see this pattern. 1=(1^2),4=(2^2),9=(3^2),16=(4^2),25=(5^2),36=(6^2). Is that the answer they are looking for?

Comment: Yes, except I have no idea what they mean by geometric verification. Presumably this is covered in the chapter, which I did not myself read.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand it.

Comment: You're welcome. I'd post an actual answer, but it's 1:22 am so I think I can sacrifice the rep for sleep.

Comment: Anytime is ok. I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one odd you get $1$ which is presented by a red square.

For tow  odds you get $1+3$ which is presented by one red square and three yellow square and together they make a $2\times 2$ square.

You are supposed to find out that when you keep adding odd numbers you will get a square for the sum.

Comment: Thanks! I think your answer is answering the question of geometric verification. Is that right?

Comment: Yes,it is. The idea is that always a square is made out of sum of odds.